# I have purged GNOME desktop but it's not fully removed

Tags: linux, gnome, kali-linux

I have deleted gnome and all its configurations using `sudo apt purge --autoremove kali-desktop-gnome` but at the log-in screen, the environment is still gnome and I can even select gnome before logging into my system. I even ran this command to choose preferred desktop environment: `update-alternatives --config x-session-manager`. Even though I am in Xfce, I can still see some signs of gnome here and there. What seems to be the problem guys?

Comment: I am not sure about Kali, but on Ubuntu, Gnome needs Wayland to run. Check if you installed Wayland.   I am on Kali here, NO Gnome and no left over items  - just Xkce,

Comment: I have little experience with *removing* desktop environments, but everything I have ever read or been told, it that this is not something you do on Linux.